# codeigniter INSERT query is correct and executed but no insert is performed

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, insert

relevant code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO rel_attivita_corsi(id_attivita,id_corso) VALUES";
foreach($elements as $element) {
    $sql .= "('".$element."','1'),";
}
$sql = substr($sql,0,-1);

if (!$this->db->query($sql)) {
    echo "FALSE";
}
else {
    echo "TRUE";
}
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

The table structure:

```
rel_attivita_corsi
-----------------------------
ID            (int)   primary
id_attivita   (int)
id_corso      (int)
```

I'm using codeigniter, as you can see, the last raw return the right query, but the table in the db remain empty... running the query returned in phpmyadmin everything works correctly.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 1 - Using active records:**

```
$dati = array();

foreach($elements as $element){
    $dati[] = array('id_attivita' => $element, 'id_corso' => 1);
}

if (!$this->db->insert_batch("rel_attivita_corsi",$dati)) {
    echo "FALSE";
}
else {
    echo "TRUE";
}

echo $this->db->last_query();
```

no success, last query printed correctly but no insert happen

**UPDATE 2 - Using active records and no foreach:**

```
$this->db->insert_batch("rel_attivita_corsi",array(array('id_attivita' => 7,'id_corso' => 1),array('id_attivita' => 9,'id_corso' => 1)));
```

no success....

i've substituted fake value with real now, and the `$elements` array is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 7
    [1] => 9
)
```

**UPDATE 3**
Problem solved... there was another query after the code that deleted every record insert into the table, so the table was always empty

If you heve doubt on the flow of your code try use [profiling](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/profiling.html)

Comment: Can you show what `$sql` contains? Side question: are you escaping/sanitizing `$elements` at some point?

Comment: Why not use codeigniters active record class to build your sql statement? It would look a lot cleaner, and also sanitize your values before inserting them (which you are currently not doing). http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Comment: Can you update you question with `print_r($element);`, so that we can tell you if you are doing it right!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think you are looping wrong:

```
$sql .= "('".$element."','1'),";
```

this produces `(value,1), (value, 1) , (value, 1)`

while you need

```
(value,value,value)
```

ma che te lo dico a fare poi :P

so your query is:

```
INSERT INTO table(ID,id_activity,id_cont) VALUES (somenthin,1), (somenthing,1) etc ..
```

and you need instead

```
INSERT INTO table(ID,id_activity,id_cont) VALUES (value,value,value) ;
```

you can try this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(id_activity,id_cont) VALUES (".implode(',',$elements)."); ";

if (!$this->db->query($sql)) {
    echo "FALSE";
}
else {
    echo "TRUE";
}
echo $this->db->last_query();
```

**IN CASE you are trying making an INSERT BATCH check the Codeigniter documentation it says:**

```
 $data = array(
   array(
      'title' => 'My title' ,
      'name' => 'My Name' ,
      'date' => 'My date'
   ),
   array(
      'title' => 'Another title' ,
      'name' => 'Another Name' ,
      'date' => 'Another date'
   )
);

$this->db->insert_batch('mytable', $data);

// Produces: INSERT INTO mytable (title, name, date) VALUES ('My title', 'My name', 'My date'), ('Another title', 'Another name', 'Another date')
```

Answer (score 0):

replace the code :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(id_activity,id_cont) VALUES";
foreach($elements as $element) {
    $sql .= "('".$element."','1'),";
}
```

With the code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table(ID,id_activity,id_cont) VALUES";
foreach($elements as $element) {
    $sql .= " ('','".$element."','1'),";
}
```